# Qual é a diferença entre o for...of e o for..in?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estava dando uma olhada nessa [pergunta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319305/when-will-the-javascript-for-of-loop-be-implemented-in-chrome-chrome) e lá vi esse `for..of`.

Nunca tinha visto isso antes no `Javascript`.

Esse é um recurso novo e já podemos implementá-lo confiavelmente, ou ainda devemos utilizar o velho `for..in`?

Qual é a diferença dele em relaçao ao `for..in`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) é uma construção nova no EcmaScript 6, e portanto só deve ser usada quando os *browsers* derem suporte apropriado a essa versão, e a habilitem por padrão. Do contrário, seu código pode ser rejeitado por uma parcela significativa de seus usuários.

O `for..of` é semelhante ao `for..in`, exceto que ele apenas itera sobre as propriedades [**enumeráveis**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable) do objeto/array. Um `for..in` iteraria sobre todas elas, inclusive propriedades customizadas acrescentadas pelo usuário:

```js
function log(x) { document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + x + "<pre>"; }

var arr = [1,2,3];
arr.foo = "bar";

var obj = { 0:1, 1:2, 2:3, length:3, foo:"bar" };

var obj2 = Object.create(null, {
  0: { value:1, enumerable:true },
  1: { value:2, enumerable:true },
  2: { value:3, enumerable:true },
  length: { value:3 },
  foo:{ value:"bar" }
});

document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>for..in</h1>";

for ( var p in arr ) {
  log("arr[" + p + "] = " + arr[p]);
}
for ( var p in obj ) {
  log("obj[" + p + "] = " + obj[p]);
}
for ( var p in obj2 ) {
  log("obj2[" + p + "] = " + obj2[p]);
}
      
document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>for..of (simulação)</h1>";
      
arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  log("arr[" + i + "] = " + e);
});
arr.forEach.call(obj, function(e, i) {
  log("obj[" + i + "] = " + e);
});
arr.forEach.call(obj2, function(e, i) {
  log("obj2[" + i + "] = " + e);
});
```

No exemplo acima, usei o `Array.prototype.forEach` para simular um `for..of` - já que do contrário o exemplo não compilaria em todos os *browsers*, e segundo a MDN o comportamento de ambos deve ser o mesmo. Cabe notar também que o `for..of` se aplica tanto a arrays quanto a *"array-likes"*, de modo que pode ser usado inclusive em uma lista de nós DOM (retornados por `document.querySelectorAll` por exemplo).

P.S. Como apontado nas [demais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90358/215) [respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/90359/215), também há a diferença de que a variável usada no `for..in` recebe o *nome* da propriedade, enquanto no `for..of` ela recebe seu *valor*:

```
for ( var p in [1,2,3] ) // p será "0", "1", "2"

for ( var p of [1,2,3] ) // p será 1, 2, 3
```

A consequência disso é que, até onde eu saiba, se você quer fazer referência também ao índice continua sendo necessário usar `forEach` (mas como na prática normalmente só nos interessamos pelo valor, ainda é uma construção muito útil).

Answer (score 11):

A diferença principal é que enquanto o `for..in` itera sobre o *nome* das propriedades do objeto, o `for..of` itera sobre os *valores* dessas propriedades. Por exemplo:

```
var arr = ["gato", "cachorro", "macaco"];
for (var i in arr) {
    console.log(i); // Imprime "0", "1", "2"
}

for (var i of arr) {
    console.log(i); // Imprime "gato", "cachorro", "macaco"
}
```

Observe que para arrays, o `for..of` é equivalente ao `forEach` que você pode usar do protótipo do Array:

```
arr.forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(i); // Imprime "gato", "cachorro", "macaco"
});
```

Note que essa feature ainda é experimental, e nem todos os navegadores a suportam - então não é aconselhável usá-la.

Mais detalhes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Quase o mesmo texto, com 10s de diferença hehehe. Boa resposta!

Answer (score 6):

Aparentemente o `for .. of` cria um loop para interagir com os valores de [objetos iteráveis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) (Arrays, Sets, Maps) segundo a [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), enquanto o `for .. in` interage sobre as propriedades de objetos

> #### em relação ao for...in, na página da MDN descreve
>
> for...of - a similar statement that iterates over the property **values**
> *for...of - uma sentença similar que interage com os **valores** das propriedades*

#### Exemplo

```
let arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = "hello";

for (let i in arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "0", "1", "2", "foo"
}

for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "3", "5", "7"
}
```

O `for...in` registrou os índices do `array` e a propriedade `foo`

O `for...of` registrou os valores de cada um dos índices do `array` que é um *objeto interável*