# Diferença de comportamento entre for e for..in

Tags: javascript, for

Eu tenho o seguinte código que funciona exatamente como esperado (que é percorrer o array, mostrando SÓ cada elemento, neste caso "Miguel" e "Celeste"):

```js
var runners = ['Miguel', 'Celeste'];
Array.prototype.winner = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    console.log(runners[i]);
  }
}
runners.winner();
```

A minha dúvida é porque é que este não? Porque é que faz sempre aquele ultimo loop e imprime a própria função? Será que existe alguma propriedade implícita que não entra para a contagem (`this.length`)? Se sim, então não existe maneira de fazer isto com `for(var i in this) {` certo?

```js
var runners = ['Miguel', 'Celeste'];
Array.prototype.winner = function() {
    for(var i in this) {
     console.log(runners[i]);
    }
}
runners.winner();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema aqui é que o [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) é um método para Objetos, e vai buscar [propriedades enumeráveis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) do mesmo, ou seja: as próprias e as definidas no *prototype*. Uma vez que estás a usar um método de objetos numa array, a função é passada também como uma propriedade do objeto. **Contudo** não é uma propriedade da instância mas sim do seu *prototype*, então é possivel filtrar essas propriedades "não próprias" com o [`.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Repara aqui:

```js
var runners = ['Miguel', 'Celeste'];
Array.prototype.winner = function() {
    for(var i in this) {
  console.log(i, this.hasOwnProperty(i));
    }
}

runners.winner();
```

Porém, o `for ... in` não é um método de arrays, mas há um recente que é. Usando o `for ... of` tudo fica certo, partindo do principio que o browser é moderno:

```js
var runners = ['Miguel', 'Celeste'];
Array.prototype.winner = function() {
  for (var nome of this) {
    console.log(nome);
  }
}
runners.winner();
```

Comment: Até me sinto mal por fazer isto, peço imensa desculpa ao bigown que também explicou bem e já tinha aceite a sua resposta. Mas realmente esclareces melhor e inclusive dás um workaround para usar `for(var x in...` na mesma (apesar de eu agora saber que neste contexto nao faria sentido). Obgado

Comment: @Miguel sim, o `for..of` respeita a ordem da lista/array, e é uma versão curta para arrays como o `for..in` é para Objectos. O `for..in` não garante contudo que as propriedades de um objeto sejam iteradas na mesma ordem em browsers diferentes. Mas `for..of` respeita a ordem.

Comment: Percebido, obgado Sergio

Answer (score 4):

O primeiro, um [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) tradicional, varre o *array*. Ele acessa apenas os elementos do objeto do tipo `Array`, mas não as propriedades deles. Ele é semelhante ao novo [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Já o [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) varre todas as propriedades do objeto, não só seus elementos (por isso quase sempre não é o que deseja, pelo menos para *array*).

Tem uma [pergunta com informações mais detalhadas sobre o `for`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90352/101).

Note que ambos estão varrendo o [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) que se refere ao próprio objeto. Mas que objeto estamos falando nesse código solto? É o DOM global do *script*. Então todos os símbolos do *script* estão contidos nesse objeto global implicitamente criado. Por isso a função faz parte desse objeto.

[Pergunta com explicação sobre o `this`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37770/101).

Answer (score 4):

O terceiro índice do teu *array* é o próprio `winner`, ou seja, há o índice 0, o 1 e o `winner` (que é um índice também).

E como foi dito por @Maniero, o for in varre, além dos índices com o conteúdo que vc criou, os *prototypes* do objeto.

Comment: Percebi, Obgado Diego