# Qual a diferença do "for", "forEach" e o "find" no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, loop, for

Qual a diferença entre os 3?

`for`, `forEach` e o `find`

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/471070/112052

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O `for` é uma das maneiras mais básicas de se criar loops na linguagem, juntamente com o `while` e o `do..while`. Ele permite repetir um trecho de código um determinado número de vezes, geralmente com base em um contador e uma condição de parada baseada no valor desse contador. Por exemplo:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    // o que estiver aqui será executado
    // 10 vezes (de i=0 até i=9)
}
```

É muito utilizado para iteração de arrays (que parece ser o caso de uso que você tem em mente). Exemplo:

```
var lista = ['maçã', 'banana', 'pera'];
for (var i=0; i<lista.length; i++) {
    console.log(lista[i]);
}
```

Já `forEach` e `find` são métodos de arrays. O primeiro equivale ao uso de um loop `for` percorrendo a array do primeiro ao último índice, e executando uma função callback que recebe o elemento atual:

```
var lista = ['maçã', 'banana', 'pera'];
lista.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Já o `find`, como o nome indica, é utilizado para encontrar um elemento específico dentro da array. Ele tem sintaxe parecida com a do `forEach`, e retorna o primeiro elemento da array que atenda a determinada condição definida no *callback*. Por exemplo:

```
// Queremos o primeiro número par da lista
var numeros = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
var primeiroPar = numeros.find(function(item) {
    return item % 2 === 0;
});
// primeiroPar terá o valor 10
```

#### Documentação confiável

- [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 6):

A resposta do bfavaretto está correta e é boa. Vou complementar.

O `for` (que eu odeio que venha seguido do parentese de abertura sem espaço que faz confundir como uma função) é um [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101), é usado de forma [imperativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101). Ele indica o que deve fazer. E tem toda uma sintaxe própria.

Ele [tem variações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/171627/101) ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90352/101)) nas versões mais novas do [EcmaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181071/101) que tornam a esta forma quase obsoleto na maioria da situações.

Os outros dois são funções, você chama ela para executar. Ela sabe o que fazer lá dentro. Você deve passar no mínimo uma [função anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101) com o algoritmo que deseja executar em cada item. No caso do `forEach()` ele só executará aquilo, e no `find()` o código deve obrigatoriamente resultar em um booleano para decidir se deve pegar o item sendo analisado.

Funciona como um [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101), ou seja, você passa uma função como argumento de outra função, esta esta chama a função que você passou no momento que ela entender adequada de acordo com a necessidade e o que ela pretende fazer.

Este modo é mais funcional porque ele delega para uma função como fazer, você está dizendo apenas o que fazer, é uma forma mais [declarativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101), ainda que em JavaScript só seja possível determinar o que fazer em seu detalhe de forma imperativa.

[Esta forma sempre é mais lenta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/161763/101). E na maioria das vezes causa menos confusão. Entender escopo em funções anônimas ([*closure*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101) é bem mais difícil), e em alguns casos até achar o algoritmo certo se torna mais complicado, especialmente quando tem que manter estado entre itens sendo avaliados.

As versões mais novas permitem o uso de [sintaxe de *lambda*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114367/101) para a função anônima.

Informações úteis:

- [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101)
- [CoffeeScript, TypeScript e JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101)
- ["foreach" em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2506/101)
- [Qual é a diferença entre declaração de variáveis usando "let" e "var"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Boa. Editei minha resposta adicionando espaços antes dos parênteses nos `for` :)