# Por que propriedade de objeto é automaticamente transformado em string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou usando o NodeJs e estou com esse problema:

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
let obj = { id : { $gte : 5 } };

console.log(obj);
//Resultado: { id: { '$gte': '5' } }
```

Observe que no resultado, a propriedade `$gte` está entre aspas. Como se fosse uma string.

Como escapar disso ? Não quero que a propriedade `$gte` esteja entre aspas.

Aparentemente isso só ocorre dentro do Node. Testei o código no console do navegador e funciona como esperado.

Comment: Boa tarde, mas isso é apenas o visual, se tu der um typeof no objeto e em todas as keys tu veras os tipos corretamente. Que serão na ordem `console.log(typeof obj) object`, `console.log(typeof obj.id) object` e `console.log(typeof obj.id.$gte) number`.

Comment: Bem observado. Não tinha pensado assim. 
O problema é que se eu jogar a variável `obj` em uma função, essa função reconhece a propriedade `$gte` como string. Mas deve ser por algum erro, não esse que eu fiz a pergunta. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Se tu puder compartilhar o seu metodo, podemos ver o que ocorre. Você pode utilizar o parseInt ou parseFloat para deixar como tipo number.

Comment: As chaves são convertidas para strings, veja exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/362806/112052) e a documentação [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names)

Comment: `$gte` ser convertido para string é meio óbvio, o que está estranho aí é o valor `5` ter virado string. Acabei de executar este código no Node v10.15.0 e está correto. O `5` permanece como `Number`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando fazes `console.log({ id : { $gte : 5 } });` estás a pedir ao Node.js ou ao Browser para te mostrar algo que precisa ser convertido em algo visual. Como o pretendido tem um factor de conversão cada motor de JavaScript vai tratar isso de maneira diferente.

O Node.js faz log de Strings, o browser permite ponteiros e por isso mostra objetos que podem ter novos valores desde que o `console.log` correu.

O Node.js não coloca `id` dentro de aspas, mas reage ao `$` e coloca essa chave dentro de aspas. Se o caso do objeto fosse `{ id: { gte: 5 } }` também não colocava dentro de aspas. 
Isto são variações entre ambientes/motores JavaScript.

Como evitar isso?

Pede para o `console.log` te mostrar algo que está já convertido em `String`. Ou seja:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({ id: { $gte: 5 } }));`
```

Assim vais ter uma resposta homogénea, igual em todo o lado:

```
{"id":{"$gte":5}}
```

Answer (score 6):

Aparece como *string* [porque a chave é *string*, sempre foi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101), então não tem muito como escapar disto. Dá para escapar de ser impresso assim e aí é bem simples não mande imprimir algo que foi feito para depuração e não para mostrar para o usuário final.

Sempre digo:

[image: Fiat 147 detonado andando pelas ruas]

As pessoas veem um resultado e presumem que podem usar aquilo do jeito que lhes convêm, porém não é assim que se programa. Para programar corretamente é preciso entender todos os conceitos computacionais e dominar a documentação da ferramenta que está usando. Feito isto saberá que o que é impresso quando manda imprimir um objeto é um valor que ajuda o programador, e ele não pode ser considerado um valor válido a ser usado para qualquer coisa. Alguns valores de objetos muito simples podem ser usados desta forma, mas saiu do óbvio não pode mais. Se deseja imprimir todos os elementos do objeto deve prover uma algoritmo que faça isto, e aí poderá configurá-lo do jeito que deseja que seja impresso.

Tem diversas formas de fazer isto e aqui no SOpt tá cheio de exemplos, me lembro de [ter respondido um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122347/101). Note que não está entre aspas, que é apenas um detalhe. Outros mostram [outras formas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90352/101).