# Criar objeto partindo de um array

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte `array JS` por retorno de `$.ajax` encodado do **PHP** (`json_encode($array)`):

```
{
  "17":[
        {
          "data":"2019-03-01",
          "ofetas":"22.65",
          "decisoes":"6"
        },
        {
          "data":"2019-03-03",
          "ofetas":"55.33",
          "decisoes":"3"
        },
        {
          "data":"2019-03-05",
          "ofetas":"30.45",
          "decisoes":"2"
        }
       ],
  "18":[
        {
          "data":"2019-03-02",
          "ofetas":"78.39",
          "decisoes":"0"
        },
        {
          "data":"2019-03-05",
          "ofetas":"30.00",
          "decisoes":"1"
        }
       ]
}
```

Porém partindo desse `array`, preciso criar um **objeto** que vai atender á uma **requisição**:

No final, o objeto precisa ser do tipo abaixo de forma a usar apenas os indices data e decisões de cada array

```
var datasets = 
        [
          {
            label: "17",
            data: [ {
                x: "2019/03/01",
                y: 6
            }, {
                x: "2019/03/03",
                y: 3
            }, {
                x: "2019/03/01",
                y: 2
            } ]
         } , 
         {
            label: "18",
            data: [ 
            {
                x: "2019/03/02",
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: "2019/03/05",
                y: 1
            } ]
          } 
         ];
```

No caso, como ficaria o `foreach` (**iteração**) no `array` do início da pergunta de forma tal que gere o **objeto** acima?

Eu até começei a fazer o `foreach` mas me esbarrei nos **colchetes** internos que me deram uma sensação de **string**.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const original = {
  "17": [{
    "data": "2019-03-01",
    "ofetas": "22.65",
    "decisoes": "6"
  }, {
    "data": "2019-03-03",
    "ofetas": "55.33",
    "decisoes": "3"
  }, {
    "data": "2019-03-05",
    "ofetas": "30.45",
    "decisoes": "2"
  }],
  "18": [{
    "data": "2019-03-02",
    "ofetas": "78.39",
    "decisoes": "0"
  }, {
    "data": "2019-03-05",
    "ofetas": "30.00",
    "decisoes": "1"
  }]
}

const novo = []

//Loop sobre o objeto original
for (const chave in original) {
  valor = original[chave];

  //Adiciona no novo
  novo.push({
    //A chave do objeto original
    label: chave,
    //Função map para formatar os objetos da lista
    data: valor.map(item => ({ x: item.data, y: item.decisoes }))
  });
}

console.log(novo);
```

Comment: Oi, fantático. Mas esse objeto não aceita as aspas nos índides será que vai funcionar? É que é paa geração de gráficos. Perceba pelo exemplo que postei!

Comment: As as pas não deveriam fazer diferença alguma. Da algum erro?

Comment: Rapaz testei aqui e não deu erro não. É que na documentação da biblicoteca não tem aspas nos íncices. Se for muito complicado deixa. Mas se fo tranqulo, retira as aspas fazendo favor?

Comment: Carlos, aspas servem apenas para marcação quando você está declarando um objeto. As aspas não existem no objeto em si depois que ele é construído. Não existe diferença entre um objeto construído utilizando aspas na declaração, e um objeto construído sem utilizar aspas.

Comment: Sobre as aspas, entenda melhor lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/362777/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365880/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/112052)

Answer (score 0):

Segue outra forma:

```
var original = {
      "17": [{
        "data": "2019-03-01",
        "ofetas": "22.65",
        "decisoes": "6"
      }, {
        "data": "2019-03-03",
        "ofetas": "55.33",
        "decisoes": "3"
      }, {
        "data": "2019-03-05",
        "ofetas": "30.45",
        "decisoes": "2"
      }],
      "18": [{
        "data": "2019-03-02",
        "ofetas": "78.39",
        "decisoes": "0"
      }, {
        "data": "2019-03-05",
        "ofetas": "30.00",
        "decisoes": "1"
      }]
    }

    var datasets =  Object.keys(original).reduce( (a,c) => { var newObj = { label: c, data: original[c].map(i => { return {x: i.data, y: i.decisoes}; } ) }; return a.concat(newObj); }, []);
```